# Canvas drawing over a status bar

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I've made a program that draws shapes based on user input. I can currently only draw a circle. When I draw circles, its radius is based on the `x` displacement and is not dependent on the `y`. This means that I can make shapes that are bigger than the available window size. When I do this, it draws over the status bar like so:

[image]

Any idea how I could fix this? Here is the structure of the XAML

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="New"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Open"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Save"></MenuItem>
            <Separator/>
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" Click="MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StatusBar x:Name="status" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="22">
        <TextBlock x:Name="statusText"></TextBlock>
    </StatusBar>
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#EEE"></SolidColorBrush>
            </StackPanel.Background>
            <Button Padding="3,0" Margin="5" Click="CircleButton_Click">Circle</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas Background="White"  x:Name="canvas" MouseLeftButtonDown="CanvasDownHandler" MouseMove="CanvasMoveHandler" MouseLeftButtonUp="CanvasUpHandler">

        </Canvas>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set ClipToBounds=true for the canvas like this:

```
<Canvas Background="White"  x:Name="canvas" MouseLeftButtonDown="CanvasDownHandler" MouseMove="CanvasMoveHandler" MouseLeftButtonUp="CanvasUpHandler" ClipToBounds=true>
```

this makes sure the elements inside the canvas don't draw outside the canvas itself

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly only change this line:

`<StatusBar x:Name="status" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="22" Panel.ZIndex="100">`

Panel.ZIndex="100" is property which tell the canvas order of painting.